# Implementation of Random Forest Classifier

Tags: java, machine-learning, random-forest

As a part of college project I have to implement random forest classifier in java . My question is which algorithm should I use generation of trees ? I want to do a very basic implementation of RFC and improving it over time.

Comment: Basically, CART, but with a random restriction of variables at each node.

Comment: Take a look at the R or C code for random forests to see how it is done there.